# Using tshark with bluetooth traffic

Tags: networking, bluetooth

I have a question in regards to using tshark with bluetooth traffic. I know that I can specify an interface to be used with tshark, but I do not know how to specify a bluetooth interface or if this is even possible?

I know that wiresharks GUI can be used to look at bluetooth traffic so I wanted to achieve the same but through the terminal.

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Reading (well, searching) `man wireshark` ( from the `SEE ALSO` of `man tshark`) led me to

```
   Wireshark can read / import the following file formats:
...
·   Linux Bluez Bluetooth stack hcidump -w traces
```

and `man hcidump` shows me:

```
NAME

       hcidump - Parse HCI data

SYNOPSIS

       hcidump [-h]
       hcidump [option [option...]] [filter]

DESCRIPTION

       hcidump  reads raw HCI data coming from and going to a Bluetooth device
       (which can be specified with  the  option  -i,  default  is  the  first
       available  one)  and  prints  to  screen commands, events and data in a
       human-readable form. Optionally, the dump can  be  written  to  a  file
       rather  than  parsed,  and  the dump file can be parsed in a subsequent
       moment.
```